how can i use hooks like 'useState' in async , await server component?

'use client'
async function Teachers (){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/teachers',
        
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    const [showNames , setShowNames] = useState(false);

    const teacherHandler = ()=>{
    setShowNames (!showNames)
}
    return (
        
    <div className="mt-10">
        <div className=" text-center font-DanaDemiBold text-3xl text-white">
            <h1 className="w-full bg-slate-900 mb-5">Teachres</h1>
            <button onClick={teacherHandler} className="p-3 bg-green-600 rounded-lg mt-5">Show/Hide Teachers Name</button>
     );
        </div>
        <div className=" flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap p-2 gap-3 my-10 ">
            {
            !showTeachers?null :
            data.map(item=>(      
            <div key={item.id} className=" w-1/3 h-[300px] flex justify-between items-center shadow-lg bg-slate-300 rounded-lg  ">
                <div className="flex flex-col m-10 gap-y-5">
                <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> Name: </h3>
                    <span>{item.firstname}</span>
                    <span>{item.lastname}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3>    Email: </h3>
                    <span>{item.email}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3>  Date of Birth: </h3>
                    <span>{item.birthDate}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3>   phone: </h3>
                    <span>{item.mobile}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3>     Address: </h3>
                    <span>{item.address}</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="w-36 h-36 m-10">
                    <img className="rounded-full" src={item.profileImg} alt="profile"/>
                </div>
            </div>
     ))}
   </div>
    </div>
    
    )
}

export default Teachers;


Thank for Your Answers. Please help me, I cant use Button and the function that handle button and I receive this error: Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components.

Does this answer your question? Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components in next.js

No, how i can use the "teacherHandler" function ?

are you using App router or Pages Router?

Next.js does not support async Client component, so you may think of using server component instead, but then a new issue will arise, server component does not support event listeners.
So the easiest way to use async in client component is to add useEffect to handle side effects, then set the data in state to use it.
Note: you should always handle errors when dealing with API's, placing console.error inside Try-Catch is not enough tho.
"use client";
function Teachers() {
  const [showNames, setShowNames] = useState(false);
  const [studentsData, setStudentsData] = useState();
  // use it to call async function
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/teachers");
      const data = await response.json();
      setStudentData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  const teacherHandler = () => {
    setShowNames(!showNames);
  };
  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <div className=" text-center font-DanaDemiBold text-3xl text-white">
        <h1 className="w-full bg-slate-900 mb-5">Teachres</h1>
        <button
          onClick={teacherHandler}
          className="p-3 bg-green-600 rounded-lg mt-5"
        >
          Show/Hide Teachers Name
        </button>
        );
      </div>
      <div className=" flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap p-2 gap-3 my-10 ">
        {!showTeachers
          ? null
          : studentDatas.map((item) => (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                className=" w-1/3 h-[300px] flex justify-between items-center shadow-lg bg-slate-300 rounded-lg  "
              >
                <div className="flex flex-col m-10 gap-y-5">
                  <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> Name: </h3>
                    <span>{item.firstname}</span>
                    <span>{item.lastname}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> Email: </h3>
                    <span>{item.email}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> Date of Birth: </h3>
                    <span>{item.birthDate}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> phone: </h3>
                    <span>{item.mobile}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                    <h3> Address: </h3>
                    <span>{item.address}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="w-36 h-36 m-10">
                  <img
                    className="rounded-full"
                    src={item.profileImg}
                    alt="profile"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Teachers;


What do you mean by "Try-Catch is not enough tho"?

@D.Rattansingh Sorry for the confusion, I meant placing console.error inside Try-Catch is not enough tho , I have edited my answer.
